# How to update rows between two different sets of criteria in SQL Server without using a loop

Tags: sql-server, loops, sql-update, range, between

**Issue**: How to update rows between two different sets of criteria in SQL Server without using a loop (SQL Server 2014).  In other words, for each row in a result set, how to update every row between the first occurrence (with one criterion) and the second occurrence (with different criteria).  I think part of the issue is trying to run a TOP N query for every row in the query.

**Specifically**: 
In the example starting table below, how can I update the last 2 columns of dates where:

1. Update rows between the null Category rows and the last consecutive "M" Category row if the null Category row is preceded by a "S" Category. Category can contain any order of "S", "M", or null.
2. Set StartDate = IDEndDate+1 day of the "S" row preceding the null row.
3. Set EndDate = IDEndDate of the last row with a "M" Category.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff94a/157).

**Notes**: I have done this in the past with a loop (fetch..) but I am trying to do this with a few queries instead kind of like:

step 1: Get work: select all valid null rows (beginning of range)

step 2: for each row above, select the related last "M" row (end of range) and then run a query to update the StartDate, EndDates in each range.

```
Starting Table:
ID  IDStartDate IDEndDate   Category
------------------------------------
11  2017-01-01  2017-01-31  S
11  2017-02-02  2017-02-03  null
11  2017-02-03  2017-03-31  M
11  2017-04-01  2017-04-30  M
22  2017-05-01  2017-06-15  S
22  2017-06-16  2017-06-20  null
22  2017-06-21  2017-06-25  M
22  2017-06-26  2017-06-27  null
22  2017-06-28  2017-06-29  S
22  2017-06-30  2017-07-05  M
33  2017-06-30  2017-07-14  M
33  2017-07-15  2017-07-20  S
33  2017-07-21  2017-07-25  null
44  2018-06-30  2018-07-14  S
44  2018-07-15  2018-07-20  M
44  2018-07-21  2018-07-25  null


Desired Ending Table:
ID  IDStartDate IDEndDate  Category StartDate   EndDate 
----------------------------------------------------------
11  2017-01-01  2017-01-31 S        
11  2017-02-02  2017-02-03 null     2017-02-01  2017-04-30  
11  2017-02-03  2017-03-31 M        2017-02-01  2017-04-30
11  2017-04-01  2017-04-30 M        2017-02-01  2017-04-30
22  2017-05-01  2017-06-15 S        
22  2017-06-16  2017-06-20 null     2017-06-16  2017-06-25  
22  2017-06-21  2017-06-25 M        2017-06-16  2017-06-25
22  2017-06-26  2017-06-27 null
22  2017-06-28  2017-06-29 S
22  2017-06-30  2017-07-05 M
33  2017-06-30  2017-07-14 M
33  2017-07-15  2017-07-20 S
33  2017-07-21  2017-07-25 null
44  2018-06-30  2018-07-14 S
44  2018-07-15  2018-07-20 M
44  2018-07-21  2018-07-25 null
```

Below is some SQL to create the table and view the query results that I have started.  I tried cte, cross apply, outer apply, inner joins... with no luck.
thanks so much!

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    ID INT,
    IDStartDate date,
    IDEndDate date,
    Category VARCHAR (2),
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date
);
INSERT INTO test (ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate, Category)
VALUES 
 (11, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', 'S')
,(11, '2017-02-02', '2017-02-03', null) 
,(11, '2017-02-03', '2017-03-31', 'M') 
,(11, '2017-04-01', '2017-04-30', 'M') 
,(22, '2017-05-01', '2017-06-15', 'S')
,(22, '2017-06-16', '2017-06-20', null)
,(22, '2017-06-21', '2017-06-25', 'M')
,(22, '2017-06-26', '2017-06-27', null)
,(22, '2017-06-28', '2017-06-29', 'S')
,(22, '2017-06-30', '2017-07-05', 'M')
,(33, '2017-06-30', '2017-07-14', 'M')
,(33, '2017-07-15', '2017-07-20', 'S')
,(33, '2017-07-21', '2017-07-25', null)
,(44, '2018-06-30', '2018-07-14', 'S')
,(44, '2018-07-15', '2018-07-20', 'M')
,(44, '2018-07-21', '2018-07-25', null);


--**************************
--results: shows first rows of each range
--**************************
;with cte as
(
select *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS RowNum
,LAG(IDEndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS lastIDEndDate
,LAG(Category) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS lastCategory
,LEAD(Category) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS nextCategory
from test
)
select *  --select first row of each range to update
from cte
where Category is null and lastCategory = 'S' and nextCategory = 'M'


--*******************************
--6 of 8 "new" values are correct (missing NewEndDate for first range)
--*******************************
;with cte as
(
SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS RowNum
,LAG(IDEndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS lastIDEndDate
,LAG(Category) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS lastCategory
,LEAD(Category) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS nextCategory
FROM test
), cte2 as
(
select *        --find the first/start row of each range
,LAG(RowNum) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS lastRowNum
,IIF(Category is null and lastCategory = 'S' and nextCategory = 'M', DateAdd(day, 1, lastIDEndDate), null) as NewStartDate
,IIF(Category is null and lastCategory = 'S' and nextCategory = 'M', RowNum, null) as NewStartRowNum
from cte
)
select t1.*, t3.*
from cte2 t1
outer apply
(       
  select top 1   --find the last/ending row of each range
   t2.lastIDEndDate as NewEndDate  
  ,t2.lastRowNum as NewEndRowNum
  from cte2 t2
  where t1.ID = t2.ID
  and t1.NewStartRowNum < t2.RowNum
  and t2.nextCategory <> 'M'  
  order by t2.ID, t2.RowNum
) t3
order by t1.ID, t1.RowNum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. I had two major errors:

1) A Cross Apply (or Outer Apply) is needed for the Top N query to work properly. 
Using a cross apply, the Top N query will be run for each row from the inner query.
Using an inner join (or left join), all rows will be returned first from the inner query and the Top N query runs only once.

2) Filtering on "[column] <> 'M'" messed me up as it did not exclude NULL's.  I had to use instead "[column] = 'S' or [column] is null"

Final SQL found in [rextester](https://rextester.com/GUH19095)

Working code below:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT *
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS RowNum
  ,LAG(IDEndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS lastIDEndDate
  ,LAG(Category) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS lastCategory
  ,LEAD(Category) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate) AS nextCategory
FROM test
), cte2 as
(
select t1.ID, t1.IDStartDate, t1.IDEndDate   --find the first/start row of the range
  ,IIF(Category is null and lastCategory = 'S' and nextCategory = 'M', DateAdd(day, 1, lastIDEndDate), null) as NewStartDate
  ,IIF(Category is null and lastCategory = 'S' and nextCategory = 'M', RowNum, null) as NewStartRowNum
  ,t3.*
from cte t1
   cross apply
   (       
   select top 1   --find the last/ending row of the range
     t2.IDEndDate as NewEndDate  
    ,t2.RowNum as NewEndRowNum
   from cte t2
   where t1.ID = t2.ID
   and t1.RowNum < t2.RowNum
   and (t2.nextCategory ='S' or t2.nextCategory is null)
   order by t1.ID, t1.RowNum
) t3
where Category is null and lastCategory = 'S' and nextCategory = 'M'
)
update t4
set StartDate = NewStartDate
   ,EndDate = NewEndDate
from cte t4
inner join cte2 t5
on t4.ID = t5.ID
and t4.RowNum Between NewStartRowNum and NewEndRowNum

select * from test
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt on this SQL puzzle.

Basically, it updates from a CTE.

First it calculates a Cummulative sum.  To create some kind of ranking.

Then only for rank 2 & 3 it'll calculate the dates.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate, Category, StartDate, EndDate,
    DATEADD(day,1, FIRST_VALUE(IDEndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IDStartDate)) AS NewStartDate,
      FIRST_VALUE(IDEndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IDStartDate DESC) AS NewEndDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, IDStartDate, IDEndDate, Category, StartDate, EndDate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'S' THEN 2 WHEN Category IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IDStartDate) AS cSum
        FROM test t
    ) q
    WHERE cSum IN (2, 3)
)
UPDATE CTE
SET
    StartDate = NewStartDate, 
    EndDate = NewEndDate
WHERE (Category IS NULL OR Category = 'M');
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/LYC17621)

Comment: Thanks for trying. Your output is close. StartDate is off by one day for the first group.

Comment: I added three more rows to the starting and desired ending table to show variability. As you mentioned your code will not handle certain conditions.

Comment: @user610064 The new version uses a slightly different approuch. And works for the current example.  Not quite perfect, as I can imagine some edge cases that would still screw this up.  But closer than the previous solution.

Comment: Impressive. I added two more ID's to show variability. Your code gets the first two ID's correct (11, 22), but not the last two ID's (33, 44). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted the answer I found.